# Convert positive input into negative number

Tags: python

```
start = int(input("Please enter starting number"))
end = int(input("Please enter ending number"))
amount = int(input("Please enter the amount to count"))

for i in range(start,end,amount):
    print(i)
```

I want the number from the amount variable to be converted into a negative number so that I can reverse `range()`.

Comment: What does `x * -1` do to `x`?

Comment: FWIW, you can just use `reversed(range(...))`

Comment: `range(start, end, -amount)` - but simply doing `-amount` may not give you the desired output. You'll also have to check if `start > end`.

Answer (score 3):

You want to negate it *only if* the start is greater than the end.

```
if start > end:
    amount = -amount
```

Or you can tuck that right into the `range()` call:

```
for i in range(start, end, -amount if start > end else amount):
```

Comment: To expand on this, you could also do `-1*abs(amount)` just to ensure that you end up with a negative number, even if the user entered a negative number up front.

Comment: good point. I'd add that at the input stage, though. `amount = abs(int(input("Please enter the amount to count")))

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you really want, but to turn amount into a negataive number you can simply type this:

```
amount = amount * -1
```